# Extracting multiple selectors using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the html file with the following structure:

```
<div class='past_financing section'><div class="section dsss17 startups-show-sections fpg76 past_financing _a _jm" data-id="32319" data-_tn="startups/show/sections/past_financing"><div data-id="32319" class=" dsss17 startups-show-sections fss49 startup_rounds _a _jm" data-_tn="startups/show/sections/startup_rounds"><ul class='startup_rounds with_rounds'><li class='first not_editing startup_round'>
<div data-id="56738" class=" dsr49 fpe53 _a _jm" data-_tn="startup_rounds/profile"><div class='show section'>
<div class='details inner_section'>
<div class='header'>
<div class='type'>
Series A
</div>
</div>
<div class='raised'>
$1,500,000
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li><li class='first not_editing startup_round'>
<div data-id="72884" class=" dsr49 fpe53 _a _jm" data-_tn="startup_rounds/profile"><div class='show section'>
<div class='g-sash green left'>
<div class='copy'>Exit</div>
</div>
<div class='details inner_section'>
<div class='header'>
<div class='type'>
Acquired
by Travora Media - New York, NY
</div>
<div class='date_display'>Apr  1, 2012</div>
</div>
<div class='raised unknown'>
Unknown
</div>
</div>
<div class='participant_list inner_section'>
<div class='participant g-lockup'>
<div class='photo'>
<a class="startup-link" title="Travora Media - New York, NY" data-type="Startup" data-id="242501" href="https://angel.co/travora-media-new-york-ny"><img class="angel_image" alt="Travora Media - New York, NY" src="https://angel.co/images/shared/nopic_startup.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class='text'>
<div class='name'>
<a class="startup-link" data-type="Startup" data-id="242501" href="https://angel.co/travora-media-new-york-ny">Travora Media - New York, NY</a>
</div>
<div class='tags'>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li><li class='first not_editing startup_round'>
<div data-id="12714" class=" dsr49 fpe53 _a _jm" data-_tn="startup_rounds/profile"><div class='show section'>
<div class='details inner_section'>
<div class='header'>
<div class='type unknown'>
No Stage
</div>
<div class='date_display'>Dec  3, 2010</div>
</div>
<div class='raised'>
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://venturebeat.com/2010/12/03/nileguide-funding/">$3,500,000</a>
</div>
<a class="read_press" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://venturebeat.com/2010/12/03/nileguide-funding/">Read Press</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I want to extract information for every `li` element in `ul`. I'm looking for founding round data, date and money raised during this round.

So far I came with the following xPath expressions:

```
    funding_round = '//div[@class="past_financing section"]/div/div/ul[@class="startup_rounds with_rounds"]/li/div/div/div/div/div[@class="type"]/text()'
    funding_date = '//div[@class="past_financing section"]/div/div/ul[@class="startup_rounds with_rounds"]/li/div/div/div/div/div[@class="date_display"]/text()'

    founders_url = response.xpath(founder_url_path).extract()
    founder_name = response.xpath(founder_name).extract()
```

Although it works fine as an output I get two separated list

```
['\nSeries A\n', '\nAcquired\nby Travora Media - New York, NY\n', '\nSeries B\n', ]

['Apr  1, 2012', 'Dec  3, 2010', 'Jun  5, 2008']
```

The concatenation didn't help either.

```
 funding_round = response.xpath(funding_round).extract() + response.xpath(funding_date).extract()
```

The problem is that the site structure is inconsistent, some of `li` elements doesn't have information about date or money. I'd better want to retrieve a tuple of objects from one query.

The final list should looks like:

```
[('\nSeries A\n', ) ('\nAcquired\nby Travora Media - New York, NY\n','Apr  1, 2012'), (, 'Dec  3, 2010'), ('\nSeries B\n','Jun  5, 2008') ]
```

Is it possible to do using scrapy?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiples options, I will use css selector to simplify but it would be the same using xpaths too.

1) If both lists had the same size you can use zip:

```
titles = response.css('li .type::text').extract()
raised = response.css('li .raised::text').extract()
list(zip(titles, raised))
>>> [('\nSeries A\n', '\n$1,500,000\n'),
     ('\nAcquired\nby Travora Media - New York, NY\n', '\nUnknown\n'),
     ('\nNo Stage\n', '\n')]
```

2) If lists have different sizes, then you can iterate over the `li` elements:

```
for li_selector in response.css('li'):
    title =  li_selector.css('.type::text').extract_first()
    raised = li_selector.css('.raised::text').extract_first()
    # use title and raised vars
```

Notice that in these case you should use `extract_first` to get only the first element and not a list of elements. Also, some of the extracted values will be `None`, otherwise, both list would be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you stop the path at `'//div[@class="past_financing section"]/div/div/ul[@class="startup_rounds with_rounds"]/li/div/div/div/div/'` (or even one step higher, it seems) and then process/parse the corresponding html fragments?
The first part of the other answer is not likely to work, but the second part working at the li level looks fine!